# Interface Builder won't show objects in existing XCode project?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I'm downloading and modifying an xcode project for a school project, but I have a weird problem. When I open the xib files, interface builder won't show any of the objects, even though the project is nearly complete as is. When I build and run it, it works just fine and shows everything where it should be, but why can't I view all of these items for editing in interface builder?

The file can be found here:
http://compsci.cis.uncw.edu/~pattersone/courses/275/resources/JSONFlickrPart3.zip

any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you don't see the window, then you just have to click on the window under the objects tab.

Comment: I'm seeing nothing other than the view in the xib.  do you have a screenshot of what it is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything has to be in a xib. it looks like the search field and other elements are created in code in `loadView`. Were you told that all of the UI elements where supposed to be in the xib, or what? Was your assignment to take a xib reliant project and convert it to a purely programmatic one?